# Python - Variables and Loops

Tags: python, loops, variables

i'm having some trouble getting my head around python i'm sure it's something simple but i just can't get it to work.

What i'm trying to do is start my script with default variables. once it's processed then go to sleep for a set amount of time - then loop back through the script keeping any variables it's updated ( if any )

i can get it to work with the looping and i can get my counts to increase however i can't get my variable of date_time to update to the current time on the loop as it holds the time from when the script very first ran.

Here is a base code I've been playing with to try and get to work with my main code but i cant get the base code to work the way i want it too

```
import datetime
import time

date_time = datetime.datetime.now()
redsent_time = '00:00:00.00'
f = '%H:%M:%S.%f'

tred = redsent_time
tred2 = date_time.time()
tred3 = str(tred2) #converts tred2 into a sting value instead of a command
d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(tred, f)
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(tred3, f)

def exec_code():
    counter = 0
    while True:

     if ((d2-d1).total_seconds()) >= 1:
        counter += 1
        print((d2-d1).total_seconds())
        print counter
        time.sleep(10)

while exec_code(): pass
```

The result looks like this

```
37432.657
1
37432.657
2
37432.657
3
37432.657
4
37432.657
5
```

so you can see the time difference from midnight to my current time is always the same even though for each count 10 seconds has passed.

Comment: You're never assigning to `d1` or `d2` inside the loop, why would you expect the result of `d2-d1` to change?

Comment: `whle exec_code():` doesn't make sense. First of all, `exec_code()` doesn't return a value, so what are you testing with the `while`? Second, `exec_code()` contains an infinite loop, since it uses `while True:` and there's no `break` statement in the loop.

Comment: The while loop in your `exec_code()` function will never terminate, there is no reason to call it within a loop as well. EDIT: Yeah, what they said

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are sleeping for 10 seconds as well as comparing times. Unless you need precision (which you won't get sleeping for 10 seconds anyway), just sleeping for the required amount of time should suffice.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, you just want to run a number of commands every `x` seconds until the program is terminated. Is this correct?

Comment: Thanks for all the replies guy's.

Barmar hit the nail on the head.

the wait 10s was only for testing purposes

i'm still learning python and getting my head around the functions sorry for the noob questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the assignment of `d2`, and all the variables it depends on that could change, inside the loop. Otherwise, you're just repeatedly using the same value of `d2`, so of course you get the same time difference.

```
import datetime
import time

date_time = datetime.datetime.now()
redsent_time = '00:00:00.00'
f = '%H:%M:%S.%f'

tred = redsent_time
d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(tred, f)

def exec_code():
    counter = 0
    while True:

     tred2 = date_time.time()
     tred3 = str(tred2) #converts tred2 into a sting value instead of a command
     d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(tred3, f)

     if ((d2-d1).total_seconds()) >= 1:
        counter += 1
        print((d2-d1).total_seconds())
        print counter
        time.sleep(10)

exec_code()
```